# Hibernate: Batch delete with executeUpdate() does not clear first level cache

Tags: java, hibernate

My intention is to use `executeUpdate()` to perform a single DELETE instead of looping through `session.delete()`, which is incredibly chatty.

The problem I'm facing is by doing `executeUpdate()`, it doesn't evict the existing deleted entities from first level cache.

Here's a very simple example:-

```
final Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

System.out.println("---------------------------------");
System.out.println("What's currently in 1st level cache");
System.out.println("---------------------------------");

for (Object o : session.getStatistics().getEntityKeys()) {
    EntityKey entityKey = (EntityKey) o;
    System.out.println(entityKey.getEntityName() + " -> " + entityKey.getIdentifier());
}

System.out.println("---------------------------------");
System.out.println("Ensure there are 3 project users");
System.out.println("---------------------------------");

checkArgument(session.createQuery("from ProjectUser").list().size() == 3);

System.out.println("---------------------------------");
System.out.println("Deleting all 3 project users");
System.out.println("---------------------------------");

checkArgument(session.createQuery("delete from ProjectUser").executeUpdate() == 3);

session.flush();

System.out.println("---------------------------------");
System.out.println("Latest state in 1st level cache");
System.out.println("---------------------------------");

for (Object o : session.getStatistics().getEntityKeys()) {
    EntityKey entityKey = (EntityKey) o;
    System.out.println(entityKey.getEntityName() + " -> " + entityKey.getIdentifier());
}
```

This is the print out I'm seeing:-

```
---------------------------------
What's currently in 1st level cache
---------------------------------
testHibernate.domain.ProjectUser -> 2
testHibernate.domain.ProjectUser -> 1
testHibernate.domain.User -> 1
testHibernate.domain.ProjectUser -> 3
testHibernate.domain.User -> 3
testHibernate.domain.Project -> 1
testHibernate.domain.User -> 2
---------------------------------
Ensure there are 3 project users
---------------------------------
Hibernate: 
    select
        projectuse0_.projectUserId as projectU1_1_,
        projectuse0_.datetime as datetime2_1_,
        projectuse0_.projectId as projectI3_1_,
        projectuse0_.userId as userId4_1_ 
    from
        projectUser projectuse0_
[TRACE] [BasicExtractor] [extract:74] - Found [1] as column [projectU1_1_]
[TRACE] [BasicExtractor] [extract:74] - Found [2] as column [projectU1_1_]
[TRACE] [BasicExtractor] [extract:74] - Found [3] as column [projectU1_1_]
---------------------------------
Deleting all 3 project users
---------------------------------
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        projectUser
---------------------------------
Latest state in 1st level cache
---------------------------------
testHibernate.domain.ProjectUser -> 2
testHibernate.domain.ProjectUser -> 1
testHibernate.domain.User -> 1
testHibernate.domain.ProjectUser -> 3
testHibernate.domain.User -> 3
testHibernate.domain.Project -> 1
testHibernate.domain.User -> 2
```

As you can see, `testHibernate.domain.ProjectUser` entities are still lingering around in 1st level cache even though they are already deleted.

My question is how do I clear the deleted entities from first level cache using `executeUpdate()` approach? Is there any official documentation explaining about this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution but it's really untidy.

BaseEntity is just a base class for all our entities.

```
@PersistenceContext
transient EntityManager entityManager;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void evict(Class<? extends BaseEntity> c)
{
    HibernateEntityManager hem = entityManager.unwrap(HibernateEntityManager.class);

    Session session = hem.getSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery("select o from " + c.getSimpleName() + " o where isObsolete = false AND isDeleted = false");

    List<? extends BaseEntity> entities = (List<? extends BaseEntity>) query.list();

    for (BaseEntity e : entities)
    {
        session.evict(e);
    }
}
```